# How to extract all files that match/ contain a string regardless of files extension and copying to another folder using CMD

Tags: string, cmd, copy, contains

Im using this but i should specify the exact file names in a list. File name in the list (Test1.pdf) I have two files with the name TEST1 & TEST2.pdf My main purpose is i want to get duplicate files which get renamed for example 123456.pdf & 123456 (2).pdf both has to get copied mostly regardless of the file extension .pdf

```
@ECHO ON

SET FileList=C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28\Desktop\TESTING\FileList.txt
SET Source=C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28\Desktop\
SET Destination=C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28\Desktop\TESTING\

FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=*" %%F IN ("%FileList%") DO XCOPY /F /Y "%Source%\%%~F" "%Destination%\"

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: `"%Source%\%%~nF*.%%~xF"`?

Comment: Not working. Much better if regardless of extension If only the text thats inside Filelist.txt
If the Filelist.txt has text TEST, it should copy all files that contain TEST.txt TEST.pdf TEST (2). whatever

Comment: `"%Source%\%%~nF*`

Comment: Please also change ```SET Source=C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28\Desktop\``` and ```SET Destination=C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28\Desktop\TESTING\``` to ```SET "Source=C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28\Desktop"``` and ```SET "Destination=C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28\Desktop\TESTING"``` respectively. I'd also advise using the same recommended syntax, ```SET "FileList=C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28\Desktop\TESTING\FileList.txt"``` too. Please also be aware, if this is run by the logged in user, that each instance of ```C:\Users\CPU-LAPTOP-28``` can be replaced with ```%UserProfile%```.